# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error message in netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: sql, oracle, netbeans

when i was trying to delete all records form Oracle database using the following code i got this exception,

> QUERYY::  delete from DMUSER.CAMERA_DATA1
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Actually here I wanted to create a data mining application using oracle SQL developer and the netbeans IDE. So my workflow is looks like as follow in oracle SQL developer,

[image]

The code part that I have used to delete a record from database as follows,

```
public void deleteData()throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "delete from DMUSER.CAMERA_DATA1";

    System.out.println("QUERYY::  " + query);
    try {
        stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
        int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        if (rs > 0) {
            System.out.println("<-------------------Record Deleted--------------->");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }

    }
```

I'm very new to the environment and searched many related questions even in stack but couldn't find exact answer which makes my work successful. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You need to acknowledge the response and let everyone know, if problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QUERYY:: delete from DMUSER.CAMERA_DATA1
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

You need to check, if `CAMERA_DATA1` table/view exists in `DMUSER` schema or not.

Try connecting to same database and schema and check, if table exist or not. If not, then you need to create this table/view in same schema.

Referring to your screenshot provided, I can see `CAMERA_DATA` table instead of `CAMERA_DATA1`. So, you can either correct the SQL query to below

```
 String query = "delete from DMUSER.CAMERA_DATA";
```